# How to create a function to drop and recreate a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a quite long script in R used for web scraping. I am using the rvest function to scrape and the rodbc to write my data to a SQL server database.

I want my code to navigate the breadcrumbs of a site and write the results to a vector called scrapeRow, then I want to write that vector to a one-row data frame called scrapeDF, and then write that data frame to my SQL server. Finally, I want to drop the data frame and recreate an empty version in which to write in the next vector. I never want the data frame to contain more than 1 row at a time.

The "write" step can happen at multiple points during the script depending on how many breadcrumbs there are. Due to this, I would like to define a function that will "clear out" the data frame and rebuild it after it is written to the DB.

I have code written as such:

```
clearScrapeDF <- function(x) {
     if(exists('scrapeDF')) {rm(x)}
     x <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=1, ncol=13));
     names(x) = c(
     'cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5', 
     'Prod', 'Prod_Url', 'Prod_Name', 
     'Vendor', 'Vend_Prod', 'Price', 'UOM', 'MetaLoadDt')}
```

The individual lines inside the function do exactly what I want them to do when x is replaced with "scrapeDF". However clearScrapeDF(scrapeDF) does nothing to the existing scrapeDF data frame, nor does it create one if one doesn't exist.

I believe I have a fundamental misunderstanding of the way functions work in R.
Please help me understand how to programmatically drop the data frame and rebuild it within a loop. I would like to call this within a function because it will be in many separate parts of my code. Thanks.

Comment: You are looking for: add `x` or `return(x)` to the last line of your function. Then call `output = clearScrapeDF(scrapeDF)` The last line of your function doesn't return `x` as you probably intended.

Comment: That was exactly it! I wasn't aware that I needed to return x in this type of situation. Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Comment: The last line of a function is implicitly returned. Using `return` makes your code more readable, or it can be used to end the function and return an object before all of the code has been run. For example, `code; if (condition) return(object); more code`

Answer (score 0):

In R, functions don't change things in the Global Environment unless you specifically ask them too--with the super-assigment operator `<<-` or with the function `assign()`. In idiomatic R, functions aren't supposed to have 'side effects'--they just return values based on a mapping/function. You are asking R to do a very un-R like task.

Furthermore, I am not sure why you need this function. Seems like you could just assign scrapeDF the new set of values after writing to your db.